# How i get array checkbox value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm New in Jquery. i Have this kind of checkbox array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyfeatures[Appliances]" value="Dishwasher">
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyfeatures[Appliances]" value="Dryer" > 
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyfeatures[Appliances]" value="Freezer">
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyfeatures[Appliances]" value="Garbage disposal" >
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyfeatures[Appliances]" value="Microwave"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyfeatures[Appliances]" value="Range / Oven" >
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyfeatures[Appliances]" value="Refrigerator">
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyfeatures[Appliances]" value="Trash compactor" >
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyfeatures[Appliances]" value="Washer">
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyfeatures[Appliances]" value="None" >
```

How i will get all Appliances array value in jquery when None Checkbox is Checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8KYzp/2/

Give `None` checkbox an `ID` for example `save_value`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="propertyfeatures[Appliances]" value="None" id="save_value">

$(function(){
  $('#save_value').click(function(){
    var val = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      val[i] = $(this).val();
        alert(val[i]);
    });
  });
});
```